# Loop Multiple Form Input Name to an Array

Tags: php, html, forms, for-loop, foreach

I have a form like this:

```
</span><select data-role=slider name="ndata[0]" /><option value=0> E </option><option value=1> F </option></select>
  <span>1b: </span><select data-role=slider name="ndata[1]" /><option value=0> E </option><option value=1> F </option></select>
  <span>1c: </span><select data-role=slider name="ndata[2]" /><option value=0> E </option><option value=1> F </option></select>
```

Then, I want to insert every data to a looping process in php file. This is my script:

```
<?php
foreach( $_GET['ndata'] as $ch => $data ) {
    $flag = 0;
       if($data[$flag] == 0){
          echo "<li><a href=\"img2.php\" target=\"blank\">Sektor ".($flag + 1)."</a></li>\n";}
    $flag++;}
?>
```

I've tried that and I get some errors. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Since the loop accepts: `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` shouldn't it be `if($ch[$flag] == 0)` ?

Comment: do you want us to guess what errors you got?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want to print something like that if "E" is selected.

```
Sektor 1
Sektor 2
```

if so you should use this code segment:

```
foreach( $_GET['ndata'] as $key => $value ) {
   if($value == 0) {
       echo "<li><a href=\"img2.php\" target=\"blank\">Sektor ".($key + 1)."</a></li>\n";
   }
}
```

because, $_GET['ndata'] will return such array:

```
array(3) { 
           [0]=> string(1) "0"
           [1]=> string(1) "1" 
           [2]=> string(1) "0" 
         }
```

so above code segment helps you to print correct sector number (`$key + 1`) by looking `$value` .

if this is not the case, can you write errors you got in detail.

Comment: Yeah, that's I want.. But I've tried your suggestion, and there is "undefined" error.

Comment: can you paste the whole error ?, so we can understand the problem better

Comment: I'm using this for jquery mobile. If I run that script, the error messages is "undefined"